# Implementing Google Analytics in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, google-analytics

I am trying to implement GA in a MVC 4 application.
I got the .NET API's from Google and created an instance of AnalyticsService like so:

```
AnalyticsService service = new AnalyticsService("WebSiteAnalytics");
```

I have also configured the Google account credentials in the config file and they are read from there.
Now my question is what's a ProfileId and what's a Table Id?

[This](http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/samples/Analytics_DataFeed_Sample/dataFeed.cs) link uses Table ID. Where do I get it from.
[This](http://mahdi.ws/how-to-use-google-data-api-in-asp-net-mvc-part-1-google-analytics/) link uses Profile ID. Where do I get it from.
I am totally confused about these two!!!

The only id GA gave after registering at GA is a tracking id in this format UA-XXXXXXXX-X

Can some one point to a resource where I can get started with this?

Regards.

Comment: Just a comment, Google Analytics can be added by simply throwing in the JavaScript code they give you.  Why bother with putting code in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Profile ID you can find in your account in Google Analytics:

`sign in -> Admin -> Profile Settings` Here is a video on [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=97LsHistmyg). It uses old design, but path is the same

If it helps i'm using following Action to get statistics (Page views) of news page by newsID:

```
public ActionResult Stats(int id)
        {
            string userName = "myusername";
            string passWord = "mypassword";
            string profileId = "ga:12345678";
            string pagepath = "~/Home/Details/" + id;

            AnalyticsService asv = new AnalyticsService("GData-Version: 1.8");
            asv.setUserCredentials(userName, passWord);

            const string dataFeedUrl = "https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data";

            var service = new AnalyticsService("WebSiteAnalytics");

            service.setUserCredentials(userName, passWord);

            DataQuery query = new DataQuery(dataFeedUrl);
            query.Ids = profileId;
            query.Metrics = "ga:pageviews";
            query.GAStartDate = "2011-05-01";
            query.GAEndDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            query.Filters = "ga:pagePath=" + pagepath;
            Uri url = query.Uri;



            // Send our request to the Analytics API and wait for the results to
            // come back.

            var feed = asv.Query(query);
            var totalEntrys = feed.Entries[0];
            ViewData["Total"] = ((DataEntry)(totalEntrys)).Metrics[0].Value;
            return PartialView(feed.Entries);

        }
```

Comment: What does Uri url = query.Uri do?